# io.connect not working in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, socket.io

I'm working on a chat app that uses socket.IO. My server is working great with my pc client but won't seem to work on my phonegap app. I've included the socket.io.js file and my server is logging that the js file has been served but once I try to use the `io.connect` function its not working.
Here is my code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
   var socket = io.connect("http:/54.235.126.109:2352");
}, false);
```

It just isn't connecting to the server and my server log isn't displaying a connection, it only logs that the javascript file was served.
Thanks,
@_C1D
**EDIT:**
 found the problem. I forgot to add an extra slash to http. Its fixed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I forgot to add an extra slash to http. Its fixed :)